# comparing two lists excluding a particular column in c#

Tags: c#, linq

Consider an entity named Employee which contains id,age and name as properties

I have two lists containing the Employee details

I have to compare the two lists excluding the id column

Please help with your suggestions

Comment: What output do you expect from the comparision? Can you explain it with some example data?

Comment: In order to get some help, I advise you to show at least some effort in finding solution by yourself

Comment: There are dozens of ways you can do this. You can loop over both lists, use LINQ's Except, use HashSets, use a custom comparer. Have you tried something? Did you encounter a problem?

Comment: Without any own attemps that indicate where you´re stuck we can´t help you.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya I have to compare only selected columns in two lists and check for duplicates

Comment: You should mention this in the question. What code you have written for that? What issue you are facing in that?

Comment: What do you expect to get out of this comparison? Different techniques are better suited for different problems. Hashsets for example can produce the intersection or difference very quickly but not both of them.

Comment: You need to use `intersect` LINQ method with IEqualityComparer. Read [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.intersect?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: @HariKrishnan `and check for duplicates` add that to the question itself. It's significant as some techniques are better for this than others. And do post what you've already tried.

Answer (score 2):

This will yield all the entries that are the same in both lists, ignoring the Id Property of your Employee:

```
var employees1 = new List<Employee>
{
    new Employee(1, "Thomas", 12),
    new Employee(2, "Alex", 24),
    new Employee(3, "Tobias", 13),
    new Employee(4, "Joshua", 12),
    new Employee(5, "Thomas", 24)
};

var employees2 = new List<Employee>
{
    new Employee(1, "Thomas", 12),
    new Employee(2, "Yu", 24),
    new Employee(3, "Max", 13),
    new Employee(4, "Joshua", 30),
    new Employee(5, "Maico", 13)
};

var duplicates = employees1.Intersect(employees2, new EmployeeComparer());



class EmployeeComparer : IEqualityComparer<Employee>
{
    public bool Equals(Employee employee1, Employee employee2)
    {
        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(employee1, null) || Object.ReferenceEquals(employee2, null) ||
            Object.ReferenceEquals(employee1, employee2)) return false;

        return employee1.Name == employee2.Name && employee1.Age == employee2.Age;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Employee employee)
    {
        return 0;
    }
}

class Employee
{
    public Employee(int id, string name, int age)
    {
        Id = id;
        Name = name;
        Age = age;
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You don't need to use reflection. `Employee` is the known type in `Equals` method and also it's properties are known. So just comparing other properties than `id` property directly would be simpler than going thru reflection.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya you're right. I updated my answer. I just thought using Reflection would be better, if OP decides to ever add more properties to his Employee class, so he doesn't have to update the EqualityComparer every time.

Answer (score 0):

As the post is tagged with LINQ I have used that in my answer.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
   var list1 = new List<Person>();
   var list2 = new List<Person>();

   list1.Add(new Person(1, "james", "moon"));
   list1.Add(new Person(1, "bob", "bar"));
   list1.Add(new Person(1, "tim", "lane"));

   list1.Add(new Person(1, "fizz", "sea"));
   list2.Add(new Person(1, "buzz", "space"));
   list2.Add(new Person(1, "james", "moon"));

   var result = findDuplicates(list1, list2);
}


public static List<Person> findDuplicates(List<Person> l1, List<Person> l2)
{
   return l1.Where(p => l2.Any(z => z.FName == p.FName && z.Addre == p.Addre)).ToList();
}
```

Person Class

```
public class Person
{
  private int id;
  private string fName;
  private string addre;

  public string Addre
  {
     get { return addre; }
     set { addre = value; }
  }

  public string FName
  {
     get { return fName; }
     set { fName = value; }
  }

  public int ID
  {
     get { return id; }
     set { id = value; }
  }

  public Person(int i, string f, string a)
  {
     ID = i;
     FName = f;
     Addre = a;
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming *Employee* class:

```
class Employee
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public int age { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}
```

You can simply use *Intersect* :

```
        var list1 = new List<Employee> {
   new Employee{ id=2 , age=23, name="Hari"},
   new Employee{ id=3 , age=10, name="Joe"},
   new Employee{ id=4 , age=29, name="Daniel"},
};
        var list2 = new List<Employee> {
   new Employee{ id=1 , age=23, name="Hari"},
   new Employee{ id=5 , age=10, name="Joe"},
   new Employee{ id=6 , age=29, name="Daniel"},
};

var intersect = list1.Select(e => new { e.age, e.name }).Intersect(list2.Select(e => new { e.age, e.name })).ToList();
```